# Install PHP MS SQL Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My server name is **SERVER9**

### **System info:**

**System:** Windows NT SERVER9 6.1 build 7601 (Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard Edition Service Pack 1) AMD64
**Compiler:** MSVC11 (Visual C++ 2012)
**Architecture:** x86
**Server API:** CGI/FastCGI

My problem is, I can't connect to our MS-SQL server. When I am trying to use the sqlsrv_connect() command in PHP I recieve the error:

*Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect() in G:\www\intranet\dbtest\db.php on line 15*

I have theese installed:

1. ODBC Driver 11 for SQL

I have also included the .dll extension in **php.ini**:

extension_dir = "C:\PHP\ext\"
...
[MS SQL]
extension=php_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_nts.dll

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed the **x86** version of VC++ Redist located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679).

Comment: why the **x86** and not the **x64**?

Comment: Because the extension is built with x86, regardless of the architecture of your OS, it's backwards compatible.

Comment: I uninstalled the **x64** version and installed the **x86** version. Now the PHP won't event show up. I recieve the error:
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Comment: Ok that sounds like you've got a version clash. If you look here: http://windows.php.net/download/#php-5.5, on the left hand column of the page it clearly describes what you should be using. I'm assuming you're using IIS. It's a pain because x64 isn't officially supported yet. I'd be rich if I got a pound for every time I saw similar issues.

Comment: Seems like I have a lot to do then... I will come back to you!

Comment: Happy to help. Have fun, I enjoy PHP-SQL Server, very fun.